# Proving that $\max_{1 \le i \le n} x_i(Ax)_i \ge c \|x\|^2$ for some $c > 0$ when $A$ is a P-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone help me to prove the following? Suppose that $A$ is a P-matrix (it may not be symmetric). Then there exists $c > 0$ such that

$\max_{1 \le i \le n} x_i(Ax)_i \ge c \|x\|^2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I'm having a hard time to prove this...

Comment: What is a P-matrix?

Comment: This could be of help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-matrix